# Finding the extrema of $f(a):=\left\vert\frac{4}{3a}\sin\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)\left(4-\cos\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)\right)-1\right\vert$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $0<a<\pi$.

Find the minimum and maximum: 
$$f(a):=\left\vert\frac{4}{3a}\sin\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)\left(4-\cos\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)\right)-1\right\vert.$$